# Error on retrieving url in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I'm having the following error in retrieving the url in IE.

I have the following code:

```js
 var url_string = window.location.href;
 var url2 = new URL(url_string);
```

where url_string is:

`file:///C:/Users/Desktop/Books%20List/listAuthorBook.html?id=011100&title=Hello`

I get the error:

**Invalid action for object**

on line:

`var url2 = new URL(url_string);`

Comment: In general, use a local server to develop websites as opposed to a file:/// environment.

Comment: @ChrisG Is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: Yes, use a local server.

Comment: I am a beginner, I would like to know how I can do it

Comment: If you're going to use PHP, install xampp. If not, Apache is enough.

Comment: I use javascript

Comment: Yeah, client-side. I'm talking about your backend. Apache is enough then, but you best still use [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). Install it to C:\xampp as suggested, then create a folder (`bookslist`) inside `c:\xampp\htdocs`. Put your files inside. Then go to http://localhost/bookslist

Comment: Looking at [the browser compatibility data on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#browser_compatibility), the `URL` constructor is not supported in any version of Internet Explorer.

Comment: **NB:** Even [Microsoft have said that Internet Explorer is a compatibility solution, not a browser](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/the-perils-of-using-internet-explorer-as-your-default-browser/ba-p/331732). And IE will be officially retired in June. At this point, it's probably safe to stop supporting it.

Comment: @RichardDeeming Which browser would you recommend me?

Comment: If you want to stick with Microsoft, then the latest version of Edge is based on the same engine as Google's Chrome. And if you need to access legacy applications that only work in IE, you can use [IE Mode in Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode).

Comment: Yes, always Windows. So you recommend Edge! The problem I've been having with Chrome lately is that I often find CORS errors (at the browser level). So I switch to IE to test my html files

Comment: This is not a Chrome issue. You cannot use fetch() in a file:/// environment

Comment: Yes, I was talking about another problem I encountered